# Ajax запрос не работает на Wodpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress

Есть у меня такой скрипт по обработке формы.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#ajax_form").submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/calc-price/e-mail-form/send-form1.php",
      data: $(this).serialize()
    }).done(function() {
      $(this).find("input, span").val("");
      alert("Спасибо за заявку! Скоро мы с вами свяжемся.");
      $("#ajax_form").trigger("reset");
    });
    return false;
  });
  
});
```

Он работает хорошо но НЕ на wordpress. А мне нужно как раз туда поставить.

Juery обновлен. И на этой же странице есть другой скрипт на jquerry который нормально работает. 
И именно ajax  не хочет работтать
Помогите, а..

```js
// Remove themes old version of jQuery and load a compatible version
function my_update_jquery () {
 if ( !is_admin() ) { 
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
     wp_register_script('jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js', false, false, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
 }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', my_update_jquery);
```

Comment: Версия jQuery отношения к делу не имеет. Вы лучше ошибку опишите. "Не работает" - самое худшее описание из возможных.

Comment: Что у вас в php-файле send-form1.php?

Comment: в файле send-form1.php файл для генерации формы на e-mail. Он работает 100%.
Я не буду его скидывать сюда потому что там личные данные.
Но есть у меня сайт на wordress/ sitename.com. Когда я на сайте в на главную страницу помещаю форму и скрипт не работает. А когда я на этом же сайте вкидываю тот же скрипт и форму в отдельную папку  sitename.com/papka
и запускаю все из нее, без подгрузки header footer meta и так далее то все отлично работает.

Comment: Может, хотя бы, ссылка на страницу с проблемой?

Comment: Я не задаю вам праздных вопросов. Во-первых, согласно правилам сообщества, вы обязаны привести код. Во-вторых, можете вырезать оттуда свои сильно личные данные. В-третьих, я так и не получил ответа о том, что значит: "не работает". Взрывается монитор? Падает сайт? Вы пришли с вопросом, извольте объяснить, что у вас там.

Comment: Если все ссылки (имена файлов правильные), то, скорее всего, причина в том, что используете функции WordPress (иногда люди и не подозревают об этом). Потому и хочу видеть код. А поскольку вы делаете ajax абсолютно неправильно для WP, то использование функций wp в вашем php выдаст 500.

Comment: Подставил работающий html, обрезал header meta. И начало работать. Даже не понимаю какая была причина. Скорее всего я где-то пропустил символы. Но большое спасибо за Ваше время..